# Can anyone help me with this weird behaviour of var in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> How does the fruit variable gets overwritten in the if block, but the color variable doesn't gets overwritten in the function block ?

```
var fruit = "apple";

if(fruit){
    var fruit = "mango";
    console.log(fruit); // mango
}

console.log(fruit); // mango

var color = "blue";

function displayColor(){
    var color = "red";
    console.log(color);
}

displayColor(); // red

console.log(color);  // blue
```

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9311553/3462319

Comment: For this you would need to understand hoisting and block scopes in JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript variable scope in the IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964895/javascript-variable-scope-in-the-if-statement)

Comment: @Jax-p JS does have block scope.

Comment: Hi the fruit variables are in the same scope, but the color variable inside the function is in other. Regards

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the function creates a local scope. So it creates a variable in the function scope and discards it when the function is done, leaving the GLOBAL color variable untouched.

If statements dont make a scope, so your just redefining the fruit variable in global scope.